# Can’t install openmotif22 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, centos7

I wanna to install *openmotif22* on centos 7 but I get the message from installer “Sorry, this did not work. The file is not supported.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share with us the command you are using to perform the install as well as the exact package you are attempting to install.

Are you using the steps documented here:
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/puias-computational-x86_64/openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: I stacked at _rpm -Uvh puias-computational*rpm_, I can't understand what's this?

Comment: What is returned when simply trying to install the openmotif22 rpm using: yum install openmotif22

Comment: `base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirrors.coreix.net
* extras: mirrors.coreix.net
* updates: mirrors.coreix.net
No package openmotif22 available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: Download Binary package: openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm from the site https://centos.pkgs.org/7/puias-computational-x86_64/openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm.html.   After downloading the openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm file install using: sudo yum install openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: `[root@localhost ~]# '/root/Desktop/openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm'`
`bash: /root/Desktop/openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm: Permission denied`

Comment: Great with the rpm on your local machine and you are logged in as root.  Now just run the command:  yum install openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: `No package openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm available.`

Comment: What is the output of this command:  rpm -ivh --test openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: `error: open of openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm failed: No such file or directory`

Comment: I think that I have a big problem to install every .rpm file packages.

Comment: I allowed to executing file and get this error: `bash: /root/Desktop/openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: You cannot run a RPM file directly.  The method to install the RPM is either using the yum or rpm command.  You mentioned the yum command is failing.  Try the command:  rpm -ivh --test openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: `warning: /root/Desktop/openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 41a40948: NOKEY`
`Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]`

Comment: Ok so no issue with missing libraries.  Run the same rpm command, but this time without the "--test".  So run this command:  rpm -ivh openmotif22-2.2.3-19.sdl7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: It was the solution, perfect David